# TFS 2017 - Nuget feed - Delay before restore take last package version

Tags: tfs, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm using TFS 2017, with a nuget feed.

After I published a new (non pre-release) version of my package in the feed, let's say `My.Package Version 1.0.1`, I need to wait about 30 minutes before restoring the project that references the published package.

Otherwise, and even if I see the `version 1.0.1` in the TFS Nuget Feed UI, `dotnet restore` with .net core CLI (and even with `--force` option) ignores the new version and take the last pre-release version 
e.g `My.Package Version 1.0.1-2019041501`

The csproj package reference includes wildcard for pre-release version.

```
<PackageReference Include="My.Package" Version="1.0.1-*" />
```

Same thing also happens between two pre-release versions but with a delay of 5 minutes only. E.g After I published `My.Package Version 1.0.1-2019041502`, I need to wait 5 minutes, otherwise restore take `My.Package Version 1.0.1-2019041501`.

Nuget package project use .Net Standard 2.0.3 and referencing project use .Net Core 2.2.

What is the cause of this delay?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet keeps a HTTP cache it uses to speed up identical queries to HTTP sources, and the cache period is 30 minutes. You can clear it using [`nuget.exe locals http-cache -clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/tools/cli-ref-locals) or [`dotnet nuget locals http-cache --clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-locals). I can't explain the 5 minute delay on prerelease packages though. Is it possible TFS takes 5 minutes to ingest the package after being pushed and make it available in its feed search results? I don't believe that NuGet expires its http-cache more quickly when you request prerelease packages, but it sounds feasible.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much :-D